# How to make "spoiler" text in github wiki pages?

Tags: html, github, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to make text which is either *invisible until moused over*, or, *has a "show" / "hide" button*, or some other thing, so that it is not visible until the user interacts with it in some way.

I'm trying to do this on a github wiki page. (Specifically it's for a short self-quiz.)

Basically I want to get a similar effect to what SO achieves with the `>!` markup:

> Hoho! Spoiler text!

as described in [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers) [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup) posts.

The same markup doesn't work in github, I guess that it's an SO extension?

I saw [this issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/411) about using spoiler text in *comments* on github, which was closed, but I thought there might be a different answer for the wiki pages, or a different solution based on HTML or something?

Does anyone know if there's a way to do this, or if it is definitely unfortunately impossible?

Comment: Note: There were some quite useful comments showing alternate approaches to do this on a github isuses page here: https://github.com/github/markup/issues/411#issuecomment-176907678

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Literal spoiler text as shown in the question is not supported in [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) or [the original Markdown implementation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

However Markdown supports inline HTML, and GitHub allows a subset of HTML tags to remain in the rendered output. As described in other answers, `<details>` works on GitHub.

If that's "spoilery" enough for you, feel free to use it.

Comment: Yeah... I was looking at this page, where it lists all the various markup formats they support. (It appears that they support them in wiki page editor also.) I went through the documentation of each briefly, the one I wasn't sure about was 'rst', the others didn't look too promising but maybe I missed something... atm I tend to think you are right. https://github.com/github/markup Best option might be to do it on a 'github pages' page which is linked to by the wiki or something?

Answer (score 191):

GFM supports a **subset** of HTML. For now, you can wrap your question in a `<summary>` and your answer in any standard HTML tag like `<p>` and wrap the whole thing in the `<details>` tag.

So if you do this

```
<details> 
  <summary>Q1: What is the best Language in the World? </summary>
   A1: JavaScript 
</details>
```

You get this -> https://github.com/gaurav21r/Spoon-Knife/wiki/Read-More-Test

Browser support is an Issue.

The thing with GitHUB wiki is that it allows you write text in other formats like **AsciiDoc**, **RST** etc. Probabaly there's solution in those too. These are 2 formats that are far more feature rich than Markdown.

Answer (score 112):

Building on [Gaurav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33033172/253468) and [this GH issue](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/166) here's a way to use advanced formatting inside the `<details>` tag **on GitHub**:

*Note: original answer from 2016 required `<p>`, since 2017 that requirement is an empty line after `</summary>` (i.e. before expanded contents). Somewhere along the line leading up to 2019, markdown in `<summary>` is not working any more either. You can see it's quite flaky as it's a hack/workaround, not a supported feature/use case. Also note that issue/PR comments support different formatting than Wikis (e.g. 2020 April underline in summary only works on Wiki, not on issues).*

````
<details>
  <summary>stuff with *mark* **down** in `summary` doesn't work any more, use HTML <i>italics</i> and <b>bold</b> instead in <code>&lt;summary&gt;</code> (<i>click to expand</i>)</summary>
  <!-- have to be followed by an empty line! -->

## *formatted* **heading** with [a](link)
```java
code block
```

  <details>
    <summary><u>nested</u> <b>stuff</b> (<i>click to expand</i>)</summary>
    <!-- have to be followed by an empty line! -->

A bit more than normal indentation is necessary to get the nesting correct,
 1. list
 1. with
    1. nested
    1. items
        ```java
        // including code
        ```
    1. blocks
 1. and continued non-nested

  </details>
</details>
````

Currently it renders as the following with the expected parts expandable and collapsible:

---

## Initial state

[image]

---

## Click on summary

[image]

---

## Click on nested summary

[image]

Comment: Per [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/166#issuecomment-322367328), make sure that there is a line between the `<p>` and the `\`\`\``. Otherwise this technique won't work.

Comment: Any idea how to get a newline after this?  When I try this technique it jams into the subsequent paragraph.  (Without adding a <br/> tag I mean)

Comment: Well when I copypaste your exact answer code, it shows no formatting whatsoever. So something's wrong here

Comment: @phil294 thanks for the alert, fixed. Sadly, this rots, so needs some adjustments as GitHub evolves. Added a note too, to point this out.

Comment: Thanks for the empty line tip, super helpful!

Answer (score 12):

The html element `<details>` and `<summary>` can do it, have a look:

http://caniuse.com/#search=details

Support is poor for Firefox & Edge, but there may be some pollyfills...

Comment: Although this is an interesting point, I feel like it should only be [a comment to another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33033172/2657549) (which came later, I know).

Answer (score 5):

If editing the `CSS` is an option for you, you can simply use

```
[](#spoiler "Spoiler Filled Text")
```

and then use (pure) `CSS` to give the correct appearance.

```css
a[href="#spoiler"] {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: default;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffeb8e;
  display: inline-block;
}
a[href="#spoiler"]::after {
  content: attr(title);
  color: #FFF8DC;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
a[href="#spoiler"]:hover::after,
a[href="#spoiler"]:active::after {
  cursor: auto;
  color: black;
  transition: color .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#spoiler" title="Spoiler Filled Text"></a>
</p>
```

(Vaguely inspired [from this code](https://codepen.io/volv/details/RrjooB))

Answer (score 4):

A different solution from the details / summary tags, but also using native html is to use a span with a title. I was doing something like this recently in org mode.

[image: raw text]

[image: result]