# Grav CMS spoiler

Tags: php, markdown, grav

How to do spoiler (hidden text or block) in [Grav CMS](https://getgrav.org/) with markdown or plugin? There isn't spoiler in official [markdown](https://learn.getgrav.org/content/markdown) and [Markdown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) (supported by Grav).

I try spoiler like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814161/how-to-make-spoiler-text-in-github-wiki-pages) but don't work with Grav.

`>! spoiler`

> spoiler

Comment: The spoiler works on Stack Overflow on a Windows 8.1 machine with FireFox 51.0.

Comment: @jww: I know that spoiler works on StackOverflow. But I want this function on Grav CMS. StackOverflow is only example to show how spoiler should works.

Comment: Grav uses Parsedown, which does not natively support spoilers. A port does show how to add it though: https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/issues/451

Answer (score 4):

There is now a spoiler plugin available in the official package manager and github [here](https://github.com/regaez/grav-plugin-markdown-spoilers).
That should provide the feature you are looking for.