# How can I fold content in Github markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, folding, github-flavored-markdown

How does github fold text blocks?

look at this [issuecomment](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/13582#issuecomment-419265979)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Check if this follows [dear-github issue 166](https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/166#issuecomment-236342209), which mentions:

collapsible sections are supported:

```
<details>
<summary>Click to expand</summary>

whatever

</details>
```

See [more in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39920717/6309).

> The key is to wrap the whole contents inside the `<p>`:

```
<details><summary>stuff with *mark* **down**</summary><p>

## _formatted_ **heading** with [a](link)

---
{{standard 3-backtick code block omitted from here due to escaping issues}}
---

Collapsible until here.
</p></details>
```

---

[Gabriel Devillers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4669135/gabriel-devillers) reports in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214187/how-can-i-fold-content-in-github-markdown/52215506#comment132626096_52215506) that GitLab also have a similar [collapsible section support](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#collapsible-section).

Comment: If you want to wrap only a code block, you can leave out the `---`; you'll just need the fenced code block _with an empty line before and after_ inside the `<p>`.

Comment: This also [works](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#collapsible-section) in GitLab.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers Thank you your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 13):

You can start the folded sections expanded by default as well.

```
<details open>

  <summary>click to collapse</summary>

  this one starts expanded because of the "open"

</details>
```